# How to sort rect coordinates stored in a std::vector in vertical and horizontal lines

Tags: c++, sorting, structure, coordinates, stdvector

I have a robot that prints lines on the floor and I command it by sending it a set of x,y points.
The points are contained in a file like the one in this figure that reports two rectangles to print.
[image]

I'm able to correctly collect all the points and load them into a std::vector in this way:

```
struct Coordinate
{
    double x0, x1, y0, y1;

    Coordinate(double paramx0, double paramy0, double paramx1, double paramy1) : x0(paramx0), y0(paramy0), x1(paramx1), y1(paramy1) {}
};

std::vector<Coordinate> coords;
...
coords.push_back(Coordinate(global_x0, global_y0, global_x1, global_y1));
...
cout<<coords.size()<<endl; 

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < coords.size(); ++i)
{
   cout << i << " X[0]: " << coords[i].x0 << " Y[0]: " << coords[i].y0 << " || X[1]: " << coords[i].x1 << " Y[1]: " << coords[i].y1 << endl; 
}
```

and this is a sample result obtained by the figure below.

```
0 X[0]: 62.5852 Y[0]: -36.5942 || X[1]: -62.5852 Y[1]: -36.5942
1 X[0]: 62.5852 Y[0]: -36.5942 || X[1]: 62.5852 Y[1]: 36.5942
2 X[0]: 62.5852 Y[0]: 36.5942 || X[1]: -62.5852 Y[1]: 36.5942
3 X[0]: -62.5852 Y[0]: -36.5942 || X[1]: -62.5852 Y[1]: 36.5942
4 X[0]: 62.5852 Y[0]: -76.4212 || X[1]: -62.5852 Y[1]: -76.4212
5 X[0]: 62.5852 Y[0]: -76.4212 || X[1]: 62.5852 Y[1]: -61.4214
6 X[0]: 62.5852 Y[0]: -61.4214 || X[1]: -62.5852 Y[1]: -61.4214
7 X[0]: -62.5852 Y[0]: -76.4212 || X[1]: -62.5852 Y[1]: -61.4214
```

My problem now is to understand what's the better way to create a list of x,y points related to only the horizontal lines and another list that contains only the vertical lines starting from the lowest coordinate.

The robot will move by firstly print the vertical lines and then all the horizontal lines.
In the figure below, for example, the robot will first print line 1, 2, 3, 4 and it will stop and then it will print lines 5, 6, 7, 8.
So, I need to communicate to the robot all the waypoints in the correct order.

What is the best way to create these two groups and order each lines based on their distance? The robot needs to optimize the path by firstly print all the segments that belong to the same direction.

P.S. I'm using C/C++ and Ubuntu.

Comment: "The best way", I would venture a guess, would be to open a plain text editor, write the C++ code to do that, test it, and verify that the algorithm works, using multiple cases, and only after verifying that it works this gets plugged into the existing code. That's an excellent way to do something like this, don't you agree?

Comment: There is no C/C++. There is only Zuul.

Comment: *What is the best way to create these two groups and order each lines based on their distance?* -- This is a data structures / algorithm issue, not a C++ issue.  Once you figure out the optimal data structure(s), then you write the C++ code to implement your idea.  Lucky for you, C++ library has useful ones such as `std::map`, `std::unordered_map`, `priority_queue`, min/max-heap functions, etc.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I would venture to guess: I'm asking about a "best way to do that" because I'm not figuring out what kind of algorithm I have to use so it is a non-sense to open a plain text editor and to write C++ code since I do not know what to write. It is for this reason that I started a new topic!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately, I'm not a programmer so I do not know how to use that structures since they seem to be quite advanced! P.S. there is no "data structure" tag, so I added structure because I already know it was more related to a 'data organizing' problem.

Comment: There happens to be a fairly simple way to do this kind of a thing. Just take out a blank sheet of paper, and write down using brief, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [schedule an emergency appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: I tried to do as you suggested, but I realized that it is hard to understand if two couples of points with the same X value belong to the same segment. For example, how can you understand that between 1 and 2 there is no line? We know this because we watch the figure, but the code should be able to detect it automatically. In a standard file, there can be 50 or 80 shapes like rectangles, squares or triangles.

Comment: I was able to sort the vector starting with the pair of values with the lower X and Y coordinates. Now, the problem is how to detect the correct segments. I tried to put down a scheme/diagram but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: I did it, by using a for loop and by checking if segments rely on the same axis coordinate. Thank you @SamVarshavchik